# Dividing the interval into $\rm\,n\,$ equal pieces. [Spivak - Calculus, Exercise 20]

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was doing exercise 20 of Spivak Calculus, it says

> (a) Find a function $\rm\,f\,$, other than a constant function such that $$\rm\,|f(x)-f(y)|\le|y-x|\,$$
>   (b) Suppose that $\rm\,f(y)-f(x)\le(y-x)^2\,$ for all $\rm\,x\,$ and $\rm\,y\,$. (Why does this imply that $\rm\,|f(y)-f(x)|\le(y-x)^2\,$?) Prove that $f$ is a constant function. Hint: Divide the interval from $\rm\,x\,$ to $\rm\,y\,$ into $\rm\,n\,$ equal pieces.

I could do (a) without much problem. But for (b) I couldn't do it after hours thinking. so i look up in the solution book

[image]

I can't understand how he goes to the green. (what's the intuition?) For the first inequality it's easy to see because $$\rm|\sum_i a_i|\le\sum_i|a_i|$$ but then how does he go to the orange part? And how he goes to the yellow part? (riemann sums aren't introduced in that part). Also how can he concludes that $\rm\,f\,$ must then be constant? Limits aren't covered in that part, so you can't let $\rm\,n\to\infty\,$

Is this just a bad exercise to put in that section because i would never come up with that solution?

thanks!

$$\bbox[8pt,border:3px white solid]{\color{black}{\large}}$$

Comment: For part (a), the sine function will serve.

Comment: @MichaelHardy i did $\rm\,f(x)=x\,$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first step is a "telescoping sum:"

$$x_n-x_0 = (x_1-x_0)+(x_2-x_1)+\cdots + (x_{n}-x_{n-1})$$

Notice how the terms cancel.

The orange line comes from $|f(X)-F(Y)|\leq (X-Y)^2$, with $X=x+\frac{k}{n}(x-y)$ and $Y=x+\frac{k-1}{n}(x-y)$, so $X-Y=\frac{1}{n}(x-y)$.

For the yellow line, if $C$ is constant then $\sum_{k=1}^n C =nC$. In this case, $C=\frac{(y-x)^2}{n^2}$, which does not depend on $k$.

Finally, you've shown that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{(y-x)^2}{n}$ for all $n$. That means that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is smaller than all positive numbers, hence must be zero.

Comment: Do you think this exercise was exceptionally hard?

Comment: Hard for me to remember that far back. Spivak in general is meant to be a first "hard" calculus class, rather than, say, an AP high school calculus class. @user153330

Comment: I did so far roughly more than half of all the exercises in the three first sections of spivak, is it a good result? do i now just have to see the answers for those exercises to move to another topic? thanks

Comment: I'm not following your question, and I don't know you well enough to advise you. @user153330

Answer (score 1):

Like the Riemann sum, he partitioned the interval $[x,y]$ using $x_0 = x, x_i = x+(y-x)\dfrac{i}{n}$, then he uses:

$f(y) = (f(y) - f(x_{n-1})) + (f(x_{n-1} - f(x_{n-2})) + \cdots (f(x_2) - f(x_1) + (f(x_1) - f(x_0)) + f(x)$, from this the green equation follows.

Comment: I suspect, given that this is an execise in a calculus book, the book has not covered Riemann sums yet. Just guessing.

Comment: I think we can reword the term Riemann sum as Telescope and this fits the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition is that the sum is telescoping: Write out the first few terms:

$$f(x+[y-x]/n) - f(x) + f(x+2[y-x]/n) - f(x+[y-x]/n)+f(x+3[y-x]/n-f(x+2[y-x]/n)+\cdots +f(y)-f(x+(n-1)[y-x]),$$

and notice how all terms cancel except $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Equivalently, if you divide the assumption to get: $|f(x)-f(y)| / |x-y| \leq |x-y|$, fix $y$ and take the limit $x\rightarrow y$, you'll conclude $f'(y)=0$ everywhere, a constant function.

Comment: As i said this exercise assumes no knowledge of derivatives